# AbstractAction in JButton in JToolbar without text

Tags: java, swing, icons, jbutton, jtoolbar

My java swing app has some AbstractActions that are used in both JMenuItems
and JButtons. I want to put some of them in a JToolbar inside a JButton, but
I only want the icon to show, not the text. Is there a best practices way
to do this?

Comment: hmm.. isn't that default behaviour of an action added to a toolbar?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

easiest is to add the shared action to the toolBar, this will hide the text automatically:

```
Action sharedAction = new AbstractAction("some text") {
    ....
} 
sharedAction.putValue(Action.SMALL_ICON, someIcon);
myToolBar.add(sharedAction);
myNormalButton.setAction(sharedAction);
```

If for some reason you want to create the button in the toolBar manually, you have to configure its hideActionText property to true before adding the button to the toolbar

```
JButton manual = new JButton(sharedAction);
manual.setHideActionText(true);
myToolBar.add(manual);
```

**Update**

for the [inverse requirement, solved in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17944842/203657), do the inverse, that is set the property to false:

```
AbstractButton button = myToolBar.add(sharedAction);
button.setHideActionText(false);
```

The advantage over creating and adding a JButton is to have the button configured as appropriate for a JToolBar with all internal listeners in place.

Comment: +1 for `hideActionText()`, which is the [recommended](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html) approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the value for the key [`Action.NAME`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html#NAME) to `null` or an empty `String`.

```
putValue(Action.NAME, null);
```

Addendum: As a convenience to users, put the previous string in `Action.SHORT_DESCRIPTION`, where it will become the button's `toolTipText`.

Comment: ehhh ... no (at least as I understand the question: one Action with both text and icon shared by a plain button and a toolbar button showing both text and icon on the former and only the icon on the latter)

Comment: Ah, I though one `Action` with the same icon in both and text in neither.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I observed that if I just add the action to the JToolBar the text does not appear, so make sure you're putting the action in a JButton.

```
JToolBar tb = new JToolBar();
tb.add(new JButton(sharedAction));
```

Comment: hmm .. so your goal is the opposite of the OP's, that is you _want_ the text to appear in the toolbar?

Comment: Exactly, hmm maybe I shouldn't have posted this here, as it might be confusing. I did not find anywhere how to add text and icon to the AbstractAction, after that I realized that if you add the AbstractAction to a JButton, you will see both, otherwise only the icon appears.